# Unsure how to round integers in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, so I'll do my best to explain my problem. I'm trying to output rounded values after the user inputs a low value and high value. The thing is that the output will only show the incremented values (and possibly zero as well). Here is how the increments are determined:

```
inputDifference = high - low;

if (inputDifference <= 10)
    increment = 1;
else if (inputDifference <= 50)
    increment = 5;
else if (inputDifference <= 100)
    increment = 10;
else
    increment = 20;
```

For example, if the user inputs 0 for the low and 100 for the high, it will output values 0 to 100 only in increments of 10, 0 and 100 included (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100).

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to handle when the user inputs float values. I have to use `floor()` and `ceil()` to accomplish this somehow. Here is the criteria for rounding:

- If the low input is **less than 1.0** from the preceding increment, assign the preceding increment's value to it. Otherwise, assign the value of the next increment.
- If the high input is **1.0 or less** from the next increment, assign the next increment's value to it. Otherwise, assign the value of the previous increment.

Sample inputs (low, high) and outputs:

**Input**: 1, 5 (therefore, increment = 1)

**Output**: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0

**Input**: 0.9, 20 (therefore, increment = 5)

**Output**: 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0

**Input**: 1.1, 20 (therefore, increment = 5)

**Output**: 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0

**Input**: 1, 150 (therefore, increment = 20)

**Output**: 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 140.0

How can I apply `floor()` and/or `ceil()` here?

Comment: You can't _"round"_ natural numbers??

Comment: It would make more sense to write a function that returns a value than to have all this code just splatted into place that does the computation vs. a fixed variable.

Comment: BTW do not write semicolons after the condition. It just cuts the `if` block.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inputs. I edited my post to make it a bit more clear. I understand that I can't "round" those numbers. I think what I'm trying to say is that the low and high input variables need to be assigned either the prior increment or the next increment, but I just can't figure out the logic to do that with `floor()` or `ceil()`.

Comment: `floor()` and `ceil()` only work for floating points arithmetic. You will have to create your own function.

Comment: And if you just to output incremented values why you need to "round" integers?

Comment: I don't know if I'm allowed to say this here, but using `floor()` and `ceil()` is a requirement for a class assignment. I have no idea where those functions are supposed to fit in. The low and high input values determine the beginning and ending increment values in the output.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to use those math functions in the wrong place. The code I showed in this post is a part of a bigger program. I'll try looking elsewhere to use those functions. I appreciate the time you took to respond, GaryNLOL.

Comment: @supersaiyoon Well, you can lookup the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) and check if the function descriptions make it clearer how that could fit within your task.

Comment: Hint: Divide by a factor, `floor()`, then multiply back.

Comment: *"If the low input is less than 1.0 from the previous increment"* -- there is no "previous" increment if this is the first time low and high values have been entered. I think you mean "preceding", perhaps better phrased as: *"If the low input is within 1.0 of a multiple of the increment, reset `low` to that multiple. Otherwise, reset `low` to the smallest multiple of the increment larger than the low."*

Comment: @tadman. I think that hint is the logic I'm missing. I think that will work for my needs. Thank you!

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for clarifying that for me. You stated exactly what I was trying to ask in my original post.

Comment: For C http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/
For C++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

If that is what you need.

Comment: **Seriously, the question is full of inconsistencies.** In the example you gave (0 and 100), you say that the increment is 10 but then show 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100. How the rounding criteria is worded is not very clear.

Comment: @Phil1970 I apologize for the inconsistency in my post. I'm only 3 weeks in to my first C++ class, so I'm still trying to get a good handle on how to explain things properly. I edited my original post to clarify what you brought up. Basically, the zero will be included in the output if the input to `low` is close enough to zero.

Comment: Well a **multiple of** an increment is not an increment... And 10 is not 20.

Comment: @Phil1970 Oh my gosh, I completely made a mistake with that part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code is not tested**

You write a function `double GetIncrement(double low, double high)` with mostly the initial code snippet.

Then write a function that find the maximum range (floor minimum, ceil maximum)

```
std::pair<double> FindIncrementMutipleRange(double low, double high, double increment)
{
    return std::make_pair(
        increment * std::floor(low / increment),
        /* high value left as exercise for the reader */);
}
```

Then adjust the range as necessary

```
const double tolerance = 1.0;
auto range = FindIncrementMutipleRange(low, high, increment);
if (range.first + tolerance >= low)
{
     range.first += increment;
}
// adjustment of high range left as an exercise for the reader..

for (double value = range.low; range <= range.high; range += increment)
{ 
    /* print values as you wish */ 
}
```

**Improvement**

As an improvement, one could use something like `low + increment - tolerance` or `low - tolerance` and use `floor` or `ceil` to reduce the number of computation and similar for high.

Exact formula would depends on desired result when the low number is exactly at the tolerance (as in the last example).

One could easily figure out that kind of thing with a pencil and paper or a calculator or by writing test cases.